# Can I force Android app to use a special version of webview?

Tags: android

Sence Android 4.4~4.4.2, webview was broken on  behaviors.
Is it possible to FORCE app to use a webview from android 4.3 when it runs on android 4.4 OS?
It is possible to extract webview from android 4.3 and static link into my app?

discustions of the problems:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5294

Comment: why dont you put max target as 4.3 if its all ok for you

Comment: because we can't ask our customers downgrade their android back to 4.3

Comment: Then you have to compromise it ;) you can't

Comment: Fine, it's really bad news.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to FORCE app to use a webview from android 4.3 when it runs on android 4.4 OS?

No.

> It is possible to extract webview from android 4.3 and static link into my app?

Not readily. It is a mix of Java classes and framework C/C++ code. The latter would have to be converted into an NDK-buildable library, which may or may not be easy. And both the Java code and the C/C++ code may have dependencies on other things in Android that are not part of the Android SDK.

Use `addJavascriptInterface()` to implement your own file chooser mechanism, rather than rely upon undocumented and unsupported APIs which now no longer work.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I manage to use addJavascriptInterface().

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible. Edit your manifest like below.

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
              android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>`

This will build for a lower version & it has worked for me.

Comment: It has no issue for build time, but for runtime. Users who have their devices installed android 4.4.2 are still facing this problem. Anyway, thank you for your reply.